# Mutex in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Two targets are satisfied by one rule like this:

```
foo.o foo.h :
    build_foo # this makes both foo.o and foo.h
```

Later, some targets need one, others need both:

```
bar : foo.o
    build_bar

baz : foo.h
    build_baz

qux : bar baz
    build qux
```

How do I prevent the recipe from running twice when `make` is invoked with `-jN`?

Comment: Also, there's a chapther in the GNU Make manual about this : https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid pattern rules when I can. In your case you will find that after the recipe is run, one of `foo.o` and `foo.h` is newer than the other (just use `$ ls --full-time` on them).

Let's assume your recipe creates `foo.h` and then goes on to create `foo.o`. That suggests:

```
foo.o: foo.h ; # Empty recipe

foo.h: prereq1 prereq2 ...
    build_foo
```

So now if `foo.o` is a prequisite in another rule, `make` will build `foo.h` first, creating `foo.o` as a side-effect. Then it will run `foo.o`'s recipe. Job done.

If you feel uneasy,
you could add a simple assert that `foo.o` is indeed newer than `foo.h`

```
foo.o: foo.h
    test $@ -nt $<
```

For more about this topic, check out the automake (not make) chapter titled [Handling Tools that Produce Many Outputs](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html)

Answer (score 1):

You do that by teaching make that the recipe builds *both* targets at the same time.

Your target:

```
foo.o foo.h :
    build_foo # this makes both foo.o and foo.h
```

is seen by make the same as these targets:

```
foo.o :
    build_foo # this makes both foo.o and foo.h

foo.h :
    build_foo # this makes both foo.o and foo.h
```

which is the problem.

What you need is a pattern rule that specifies both target files.

```
%.o %.h :
    build_foo # this makes both foo.o and foo.h
```

which works for this (but you **really** want to give it sane prerequisites) because of how GNU make handles [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro) when they specify multiple targets:

> Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, `make` knows that the rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets. When searching for a pattern rule to match a target, the target patterns of a rule other than the one that matches the target in need of a rule are incidental: `make` worries only about giving a recipe and prerequisites to the file presently in question. However, when this file’s recipe is run, the other targets are marked as having been updated themselves.